# В какой библиотеке можно найти HttpClient для unity3D?

Tags: unity3d, httpclient

Для использования HttpClient нужен System.Net.dll и Net4 но в unity3d используется Net3.5

HttpClient есть в

c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.dll

но он не подходит для Unity.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{}
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

static HttpClient CreateClient(string accessToken = "")
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            }
            return client;
        }
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes
>   (bool)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace
>   (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000]
>   in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces
>   (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in

Answer (score 1):

Если надо сделать HTTP запрос, а сам класс непринципиален, то, возможно, подойдет [UnityWebRequest](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) или [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)